# Corpus-making guide in Language Understanding Context

Tags: reference-request, corpora

I want to make a standard annotated corpora on Language Understanding but I don't know where to start and what to do!
Does anyone know any good reference in order to guide me through making a standard corpora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try Oxford's "[Developing Linguistic Corpora: A Guide to Good Practice](http://www.ahds.ac.uk/guides/linguistic-corpora/index.htm)", Wynne, ed..

Comment: Thanks. Is there anymore resources?!